# Jenkins console output keeps refreshing (whole page)

Tags: jenkins

When creating my first Pipeline in Jenkins, and when I try to see the "console output", the whole page keeps refreshing, making if very difficult to change to another menu option (because the build process is very fast; at the moment is a simple "echo hello".)

Jenkins ver. 2.118